# What does the parameter stop mean in strategy.entry()

Tags: pine-script

The snippet is like this:

```
    if (rsi_buy_signal) 
        strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long, stop=longStop, qty=500, comment='B02')
```

Sometimes, when the rsi_buy_signal triggered, it would not trade on the next bar. It would buy on the another bar after the bar triggered the condition.

If I remove the stop parameter:

```
    if (rsi_buy_signal) 
        strategy.entry("Buy",strategy.long, qty=500, comment='B02')
```

It would trade on the next bar as expected.

[image]

So, what does the `stop` parameter really mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The refman is your friend for answers to questions like this. See the entry for [`strategy.entry()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dentry). When `stop` is used, the order becomes a *stop-buy* order, meaning it will only execute once that price is reached. If you also include a value for the `limit` parameter, then your order becomes a *stop-limit* order, meaning it will only execute when the `stop` level is reached AND the price does not surpass the `limit` value.

When you use neither `stop` nor `limit`, the order is a *market* order, meaning it will execute "immediately" (which is normally at the open of the next bar).

Comment: oh, I misunderstood it as stop loss. thanks for your explanation :)